# Two one-to-many relationship with reference table (Doctrine 2, ZF2)

Tags: doctrine-orm, zend-framework2, entity-relationship

I've a problem with my many-to-many relation. I want to have access to the reference table for a querybuilder query. With a many-to-many relation I don't have access to my reference table, so I've set up two one-to-many relationships. My structure look likes:

`User ---> UserUserCategory <--- UserCategory`

The above structure has two one-to-many relationships and are working fine with the  database. When I have a user with the following data in the database (in UserUserCategory):

```
Table User
ID | Name
1  | Bart
2  | Gerard

Table Category 
ID | Name
1  | Officer
2  | Medic

Table UserUserCategory
User | Category
1    | 1
2    | 2
```

So Bart is an Officer and Gerard is a Medic. But when I want to retrieve the data, it said that Bart is the Medic, and Gerard has a "null" value in the category.

**My User-entity:**

```php
/**
 * Entity Class representing a post of our User module.
 * 
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="user")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="User\Repository\UserRepository")
 * 
 */
class User extends zfcUser implements UserInterface
{
    /**
     * Categories from user
     * 
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="User\Entity\UserUserCategory", mappedBy="user_id", cascade={"remove", "persist"})
     * @var UserUserCategory
     * @access protected
     */
    protected $user_usercategories;

//name & user_id comes here

    /**
     * Constructor to make a new ArrayCollection for addresses
     * 
     * 
     */
    public function __construct()
    {        
        $this->user_usercategories = new ArrayCollection();
    }

      /**
     * @param Collection $categories
     */    
    public function addUserUserCategories(Collection $user_usercategories)
    {
        foreach ($user_usercategories as $user_usercategorie) {
            $user_usercategorie->setUser($this);
            $this->user_usercategories->add($user_usercategorie);
        }
    }

   /**
     * @param Collection $categories
     */
    public function removeUserUserCategories(Collection $user_usercategories)
    {
        foreach ($user_usercategories as $user_usercategorie) {
            $user_usercategorie->setUser(null);
            $this->user_usercategories->removeElement($user_usercategorie);
        }
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection
     */
     public function getUserUserCategories()
     {
         return $this->categories;
     }
}
```

**My UserCategory-entity:**

```php
/**
 * A User category entity.
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(uniqueConstraints={@ORM\UniqueConstraint(name="unique_name_parentId", columns={"name", "parent_id"})})
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
 */
class UserCategory extends Category
{    
    /**
     * User_usercategories
     * 
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="User\Entity\UserUserCategory", mappedBy="category_id")
     * @var UserUserCategory
     * @access protected
     */
    protected $user_usercategories;

    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->user_usercategories = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * @param Collection $categories
     */    
    public function addUserUserCategories(Collection $user_usercategories)
    {
        foreach ($user_usercategories as $user_usercategorie) {
            $user_usercategorie->setCategory($this);
            $this->user_usercategories->add($user_usercategorie);
        }
    }

   /**
     * @param Collection $categories
     */
    public function removeUserUserCategories(Collection $user_usercategories)
    {
        foreach ($user_usercategories as $user_usercategorie) {
            $user_usercategorie->setCategory(null);
            $this->user_usercategories->removeElement($user_usercategorie);
        }
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection
     */
     public function getUserUserCategories()
     {
         return $this->categories;
     }
}
```

**My UserUserCategory-entity:**

```php
/**
 * Entity Class representing a post of our User_UserCategory entity.
 * 
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="user_usercategory")
 * 
 */
class UserUserCategory
{
    /**
     * User with a category
     * 
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="User\Entity\User", inversedBy="user_usercategories")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="user_id", nullable=false, onDelete="CASCADE")
     * @ORM\Id
     * 
     * @var User
     * @access protected
     */
    protected $user_id;

    /**
     * Category from user
     * 
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="User\Entity\UserCategory", inversedBy="user_usercategories")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="category_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false, onDelete="CASCADE")
     * @ORM\Id
     * 
     * @var Category
     * @access protected
     */
    protected $category_id;

        public function getUser()
    {
        return $this->user;
    }

    /**
     * Set User
     * 
     * @param User $user
     * @return User
     */
    public function setUser(User $user = null)
    {
        //die('setUser');
        $this->user = $user;
        return $this;
    }

    public function getCategory()
    {
        return $this->category;
    }

    /**
     * Set Category
     * 
     * @param Category $category
     * @return Category
     */
    public function setCategory(Category $category = null)
    {
        $this->category = $category;
        return $this;
    }
}
```

When I execute the following line, it gives back the wrong result. The wrong category pops up:

\Doctrine\Common\Util\Debug::dump($this->getEntityManager()->find('User\Entity\User', '49')->user_usercategories);
die;

Result:

```php
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  object(stdClass)#452 (3) {
    ["__CLASS__"]=>
    string(28) "User\Entity\UserUserCategory"
    ["user_id"]=>
    string(16) "User\Entity\User"
    ["category_id"]=>
    string(24) "User\Entity\UserCategory"
  }
}
```

In the category_id is the medic printed, I expect the officer to get back.

In my other user, (id=60) the category_id field is "null". So it look likes Doctrine skips the first input in my UserUserCategory, starts with the second and can't get the last category anymore.

Answer (score 1):

No offence, but I find your code very hard to read. I would suggest you to do few corrections and that might even help you in solving the problem.

1: Naming: Instead of UserCategory, rename it to Category. If your Category will have different types, create new column "type" with values from constansts like

```
 class Category
 {
    const TYPE_USER = 1 ;
    ....
```

2: Instead of addCategories(Collection $array), do singular version like

```
public function addCategory(Category $category)
{
    $reference = new UserCategory() ;
    $reference->setUser($this) ;
    $reference->setCategory($category) ;
    $this->user_categories->add($reference) ;
}

public function removeCategory(Category $category)
{
    foreach($this->user_categories as $reference) {
        if ( $reference->getCategory() === $category ) 
            $this->user_categories->removeElement($reference) ;
    }
}
```

Symfony2 automaticaly recognizes methods like this. Even if your relation is plural (like categories), s2 will find singularified addCategory and removeCategory methods.

To get array of categories, use this:

```
public function getCategories()
{
    $categories = new ArrayCollection() ;
    foreach($this->user_categories as $reference) {
        $categories->add( $reference->getCategory() ) ;
    }
    return $categories ;
}
```

If you do it like this, you will probably solve the problem you have.

Comment: My problem is fixed now. I'm using an ID in my reference table. So I don't have two identifiers anymore. And I'm not using Symfony, but Zend framework 2 (title). The UserCategory entity extends from the Category entity because there will be more categories (content, user, roles). Still thanks for your answer.